# Dependency-injection Exception when configuring EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

```
//the Startup.cs file configuration settings.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<PortContext>();
}
```

**project.json**

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
 },
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "type": "build"
 },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
  "MailKit": "1.3.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
  "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "mongocsharpdriver": "2.3.0-rc1",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
 },

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
},
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"
},
"commands": {
"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
 }
},

 "buildOptions": {
 "emitEntryPoint": true,
 "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
 "configProperties": {
   "System.GC.Server": true
 }
},

"publishOptions": {
 "include": [
   "wwwroot",
   "web.config"
 ]
},

"scripts": {
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
 }
}

    And my PortContext.cs file's OnConfiguring method is given below.

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        var connString =Startup.Configuration["Data:PortContextConnection"];
        options.UseSqlServer(connString);
        base.OnConfiguring(options);
    }
```

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add` command I am getting the exception:

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'WebApplication8.Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: It clearly says `IDbContextFactory` dependency is not registered.  Can you share your DbContext file as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response. And PortContext file is derived from the DbContext file. DbContext file which is from Microsoft.Data.Entity. In PortContext file there is nothing more than the table definitions with OnConfiguring method above.

Comment: try   `services.AddDbContext<PortContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["connectionstring path"], b => b.MigrationAssembly("host project namespace")));` You need `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package installed.

Comment: Thank you and I tried this also but MigrationAssembly is not recognized. I had to use MigrationsAssembly instead.

Comment: And problem is not solved yet , still looking for a solution. Is this due to the versions of .net core

Comment: It's hard to provide solution wihtout seeing the code. Can you post the code in `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: Please don't use the term ASP.NET 5. It's not called like this anymore. The name is ASP.NET Core. Same apples for EntityFramework 7. It's not called this anymore, it's called EntityFramework Core (and has Version 1.0.0)

Comment: Agree. Ill use .NET Core next time. I am still trying to figure out the problem here by the way! .NET Core 1.0 has many framework versions I think. I have different framework version than the tutorial I am following (https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app) . Even in entity framework commands I need to use "dotnet ef <command>" instead of "dnx ef".I think .Net core is not stable enough. If you don't agree please correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution. This problem occurs when we used multiple unmatched versions of packages of our project.json. (Mostly rc1 or rc2 versions). I have rearranged the project.json dependencies and problem has solved.

```
  "dependencies": {
//"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
//"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"MailKit": "1.3.0-beta7",
//"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
//"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
//"MyLibrary": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
//"OpenIddict": "1.0.0-alpha2-0331",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "type": "build"
},
//"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7"
```

},

You can see I have removed all rc1 and rc2 versions from project.json..NET core versions are rapidly updating. I think we need to manage our code by using only one single set of updates instead of mixing all. Thank you to all who responded.